# Prevent all subdomains from being crawled by search engine bots

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, robots.txt

I have a domain like *domaindev.com*.

I have set the `robots.txt` file on this domain to block everything:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Just like that.  So that blocks everything from being crawled.

Now here is where it gets interesting. We also have several subdomains.domaindev.com hosted on our server and I want to block all of those subdomains as well from being crawled. I want a simple way to block any old subdomains and any new subdomains. Is there a line I can add to the *www.domaindev.com* that will prevent any subdomains under the `domaindev.com`?

Is the best way to make a default `robots.txt` and just drop it in all of the subdomain folders manually.

I'd really like a definite solution so as not to have to continually do same.

We use WordPress and in the wp-admin we have set it to not let spiders crawl our websites. But somehow these websites are finding there way into Google.

How do I go about it?

I've searched the site and found this line to add to my `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

I'm going to do that as well.

I also saw that it is part of the standard that each subdomain would need its own `robots.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `Alias` directive in your httpd.conf file outside of any VirtualHost section to catch any "robots.txt" requests.

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/www/robots.txt
```